# Creating multiple hooks for theme

Tags: theme-development, customization, hooks

Iam working on a theme in the moment and got to the point where I also want to add some custom hooks to some locations, to enable some more flexibility.

I want to add multiple hooks to the theme.
I have different sections (header, content, sidebar, footer etc) and on all those locations I want to add an `before`, `inside` and `after` hook.

So at first I was using a code block like this to create multiple hooks for my theme:

```
/* Teaser hooks */
function _s_before_teaser() { do_action('_s_before_teaser', 'teaser'); }
function _s_inside_teaser() { do_action('_s_inside_teaser', 'teaser'); }
function _s_after_teaser() { do_action('_s_after_teaser', 'teaser'); }

/* Header hooks */
function _s_before_header() { do_action('_s_before_header', 'header'); }
function _s_inside_header() { do_action('_s_inside_header', 'header'); }
function _s_after_header() { do_action('_s_after_header','header'); }

......

/* Sidebar hooks */
function _s_before_sidebar() { do_action('_s_before_sidebar', 'sidebar'); }
function _s_inside_sidebar() { do_action('_s_inside_sidebar', 'sidebar'); }
function _s_after_sidebar() { do_action('_s_after_sidebar', 'sidebar'); }

/* Footer hooks */
function _s_before_footer() { do_action('_s_before_footer', 'footer'); }
function _s_inside_footer() { do_action('_s_inside_footer', 'footer'); }
function _s_after_footer() { do_action('_s_after_footer', 'footer'); }
```

With this code I can use `<?php _s_before_header(); ?>` in a template file.

With this setup everything works as it should.

**But I find the code, or at least the big code block ugly and also dont want to use duplicate(kinda) code.**

So instead of that code block I rewrote this code to the following:

```
function _s_create_all_hooks() {
    $sections = array(
        'header',
        'branding',
        'navigation',
        'content',
        'single',
        'sidebar',
        'footer'
    );

    foreach ($sections as $section) {
        do_action('_s_before_'.$section, $section);
        do_action('_s_inside_'.$section, $section);
        do_action('_s_after_'.$section, $section);
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', '_s_create_all_hooks', 10, 1 );
```

This is also working, but...

With this method I cant use `<?php _s_before_header(); ?>` anymore, cause I dont have any functions anymore.

Instead I now must use this in templates `<?php do_action('_s_before_header', 'header'); ?>`

But Iam not to thrilled with this method and Iam also finding the `do_action` snippets in my template ugly.

I already searched the web, found several hook-tutorials, but in all tutorials and articles only one example hook is created. There was no article covering the creation of multiple hooks at once.

**My question is, what is the best practice to create multiple hooks at once?**

Comment: Is there a technical reason for you to add `do_action` as a a block like this? Since `do_action` will only run code registered with `add_action`, by default it won't do anything, so you can add it straight to your markup.  This serves serves the dual purpose of documenting the theme for other developers. For example: you can add the code `<?php do_action( '_s_before_header' ); ?>` before the header and it won't do anything... until you add `add_action( '_s_before_header', function() { echo 'something'; } ) ; ?>` (or whatever) to your code.

Comment: Hi Pedro,
I was using the code block so that I can write just `<?php _s_before_header(); ?>` in the template files where I want the hooks. I have some other functions in place to already add some content to some hooks, so not every hook will be empty. I know that `do_action` will do nothing if Iam not using `add_action` to add something. I just wanted to

Comment: ... see if there is another method. So you are saying I should/can just place the `do_actions` directly inside the template files and do nothing else. Thanks for clarifying! (sorry edit span was over)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did, is `do_action` with a single parameter.

```
File: wp-includes/plugin.php
417:  * @param string $tag     The name of the action to be executed.
418:  * @param mixed  $arg,... Optional. Additional arguments which are passed on to the
419:  *                        functions hooked to the action. Default empty.
420:  */
421: function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
```

Since PHP is a liberal language you can also add multiple parameters to the `do_action` and later use the number of parameters in te `add_action` 4-th argument.

```
function _hookgenerator( $name ) { do_action($name); }
```

Feel free to test since this is how you can make it work.
In this example, I haven't used hook arguments at all. Maybe after some thinking, you will not need that also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your snippet prosti.
Before I could not wrap my head around the way you wrote this, thanks.

After the answer @pedro provided I think I had just the wrong idea how to setup hooks (or not having to setup something at all).

Regarding the do_action parameters:
Iam using the 1 parameter that I added to `do_action` to generate a matching id for some of the HTML Elements:

`function _s_theme_section_start( $section ) {

 echo '<div id="full-width-'.$section.'" class="full-width">';
};
add_action('_s_before_header', '_s_theme_section_start', 10, 1 );`

Comment: In WPSO @LWS-Mo, we say thanks using upvotes, and downvotes. :)

Comment: I upvoted Pedro´s comment (cause he brought me to the right thinking), upvoted your comment and marked it also as an answer. This is OK right?

Comment: Shure thing @LWS-Mo, good management.